# Javascript return me object Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have this code to create datatable with datatables.net plugin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
        <link type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/380cb78f450/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css" />

        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/380cb78f450/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>

        <script type='text/javascript' src="https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/KeyTable/js/dataTables.keyTable.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //   function day2Date( day, year ) {
            // return new Date(year,0,day);
            //}
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#example').dataTable({
                    "ajax": "table1.php",
                    "columns": [{
                            "data": "ID"
                        }, {
                            "data": "naziv"
                        }, {
                            "data": "vrsta"
                        },

                    ],
                    "columnDefs": [{
                        "targets": 2,
                        "data": "download_link",
                        "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                            // return data; 
                            return '<button class="btn btn-success">' + data + '</button>';
                        }
                    }]
                });
            });
            var table = $('#example').DataTable();
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td', function() {
                    console.log('Data:' + $(this).html().trim() + 'Row:' + $(this).parent().find('td').html().trim() + 'Column:' + $('#example thead tr th').eq($(this).index()).html().trim());
                    // alert('Row:'+$(this).parent().find('td').html().trim());
                    //alert('Column:'+$('#example thead tr th').eq($(this).index()).html().trim());

                });
                $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
                    console.log('Row index: ', table.row(this).index());
                });
            });
        </script>
        <div class="container">
            <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsitive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Naziv</th>
                        <th>Vrsta</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Naziv</th>
                        <th>Vrsta</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to get row index so I write as you can see from code above:

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    console.log( 'Row index: '+table.row( this ).index() );
```

like I see on documentation on datatables web site but this code return me only `[object Object]`

example:

```
Data:12Row:2Column:Naziv 
Row index: [object Object]
```

Why? Sombody have explanation?

Comment: do a `console.log` just on the object itself. developer tools will then show more info about the object, instead of just the `.toString()` value which returns `[object Object]`. so, do a `console.log(table.row(this).index())` and see what that object really is.

Comment: The only difference between your example and the example [here](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index()) is that they use `alert` instead of `console.log`, could you try changing it to an `alert` to see if the same happens?

Comment: @ Nunners: That will not (or certainly should not) make any difference.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I was hoping it wouldn't make a difference, so we could at least narrow it down to the function call itself

Comment: @ OP - Are you sure there is no extra code involved with this? I cannot reproduce this issue in any browser.

Comment: Does anyone have a working sample JSFiddle for this code? I can't get `row` to resolve correctly as a method on the `table` object: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/HEDvf/1840/

Comment: there is just table1.php file that produce JSON code ...

Comment: also when I call table.row(1).index(); in console.log in browser than I get just []

Comment: The source code is UPDATED, now is full...

Comment: The only problem I have spotted is that your one line of code that references the table, is outside the DOM ready handler and before the element on the page. try moving it as outlined below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have included one key line of code *outside* any DOM ready handler, but before the element to which it occurs. That means that `$('#example')` is not returning a match:

Put this line in the DOM ready handler:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
```

e.g

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
        console.log('Data:' + $(this).html().trim() + 'Row:' + $(this).parent().find('td').html().trim() + 'Column:' + $('#example thead tr th').eq($(this).index()).html().trim());
        // alert('Row:'+$(this).parent().find('td').html().trim());
        //alert('Column:'+$('#example thead tr th').eq($(this).index()).html().trim());

    });
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        console.log('Row index: ', table.row(this).index());
    });
});
```

Comment: @James D.: Amazing the difference full code can make :)

Answer (score 2):

When you do a String concatenation on a JavaScript Object it will implicitly call `toString()` on the Object.

The default `Object.toString()` simply returns `[object Object]`.

To print out the contents of the Object use `console.log` with two arguments:

```
console.log( 'Row index:', table.row( this ).index() );
```

If I test on the [DataTable example website](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) then it appears to work as expected, and the result is a Number, so I think there must be some information missing from your question...

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable()
> []
table.row(1).index()
> 1
```

Comment: again is the same, dont work, problem is something else

Comment: does "dont work" mean that the suggested call prints `Row index: [object Object]`?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me on their example site. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The `row()` `index()` method should be returning an integer, so it would appear this problem has nothing to do with the string conversion of an `object`.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Looks like it.

Comment: also when I call table.row(1).index(); in console.log in browser than I get just []

Comment: Turned out to be the most common error of all. No DOM ready wrapping (on one key line of code)